# Server 2016 Cannot open any SSL sites

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2016

Frustrating issue here...hopefully someone else has seen this before so here goes:

**Problem:**
I cannot open any https:// (SSL) sites from any products running under Server 2016.  Non-SSL sites all open fine.

**Tried:**
Restarting.

Multiple browsers: Chrome exhibits the identical symptoms so this is NOT an IE-exclusive issue.

Software that uses SSL to communicate (ex. Windows Settings -> Updates) doesn't work.  Just runs for a while then times out with "...couldn't connect to the update service...".

DNS resolves are fine (again, non-SSL sites open fine).  Pinging the same SSL-sites resolves/replies just fine.

sfc /scannow returned no problems

Windows Firewall is turned off for all profiles.

Clearing SSL State in IE (IE -> Options -> Content -> [Clear SSL State])

Resetting IE (IE -> Options -> Advanced -> [Reset...])

Tried from multiple user accounts, Admin and non-admin alike.  All user profiles exhibit the identical symptoms.

**(Added 01/16/18):** ALL other physical systems and VM's on this hardware/subnet access all sites as expected.  ONLY this ONE VM has issues with SSL.  So this is not a firewall/router issue (hardware firewall appliance is configured to permit ALL outbound connections).

**Scenario:**
This is a production Server 2016 VM used for hosting RemoteApps services so my other users can run programs such as QuickBooks from off-premises.  This also hosts our company Wiki running Atlassian Confluence.  Both RemoteApps hosting and the Wiki hosting work fine; both are running through SSL which seems to be working fine for hosting the services.

No proxies are configured.

SQL Server 2016 is installed (and appears to be working fine)

Any ideas?  I've been doing this for over 30 years now...but occasionally I stumble on an issue where I begin to question my life directions and this is one of those cases ;)

-Dan

Comment: What about a network appliance firewall?  What about google.com?  Sometimes a root certificate needs to be updated or installed. The fact that you are getting an error with windows updates seems to be a block outside of the server

Comment: Nope.  This is one of about 15 different nodes connecting on the exact same switch.  ALL other systems, same subnet, same domain, etc are able to access ANYTHING as expected.  The ONLY node with an issue is this one server.  Google cannot be accessed as it is https only.

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED!!!**

Aaron's comment about "Network Appliance firewall" on the question got me to thinking--I immediately dismissed it outright, as everything else worked just fine behind that same firewall.  Everything in me screamed this was a root certificates, or SSL or some SSL-related issue.  In reality, it was nothing of the sort.

We're using a Sonicwall firewall, which--no problems there, they're great in my opinion.  HOWEVER, whenever a "public server" is set up (defined as a node with some ports open such that it can be accessed from outside, ex. SMTP port 25 or HTTPS 443) it creates three separate NAT rules that govern situations such as loopbacks (when a machine on the LAN is trying to access a WAN-accessible service such as apps.mycompany.com--the loopback translates the public IP to the internal LAN IP).

The issue: I was running RemoteApps hosting services on Port 443, and also Atlassian Confluence on its default port of 8433.  But since I'm running it directly on a fqdn (wiki.companyname.com) I didn't want to have to add a :8433 to every browser request.  So I port translated through the NAT table inbound requests for 443 on the Wiki's public IP (we have a block of 5) to 8433.  Thus 443 external = 433 internal on the RemoteApps IP, but 443=8433 on the Wiki public IP.

The cause: The Sonicwall was translating OUTBOUND requests FROM the server's LAN (Private) IP from 443 to 8433.  So basically every https:// request was going out 8433.

ONE LITTLE CHECKBOX!

All is well.  Props to Aaron (top comment) not necessarily for being spot on, but that whole "network appliance firewall" thing just wouldn't depart from the back of my mind, and I started thinking about that NAT table...

I was able to figure out the solution by changing the LAN IP address of the server.  Suddenly it worked (outbound anyway, obviously it completely broke all the inbound connections but I'd only intended it as a brief test).  When the behavior changed with the new LAN IP, it immediately eliminated Certs/RootCerts/SSL from the equation and got me focusing on what was special about the "broken" IP---which lead me to the blasted NAT list.